What is meant by f being continous in possible isolated points in its domain?
The definition of a continuous function in my textbook is given as follows:

$f$ being continuous in a accumulation point $a\in D_f$ means that:
$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$
We count $f$ as continuous in possible
isolated points $a\in D_f$

I do understand the first statement about $a$ being a accumulation point. But I dont understand the last statement:

We count $f$ as continuous in possible isolated points $a\in D_f$

Could someone explain what is meant by this with an example?

I know what is intended by the 2nd statement, but it's worded very poorly. The intended meaning is: "If $a$ is an isolated point of $D_f,$ then $f$ is continuous at $a.$" In other words, by definition $f$ is (automatically) continuous at every isolated point of its domain (regardless of whatever formula might be used to define $f$ and regardless of the values of $f$ at other points of its domain).

Does this answer your question? Can a function with just one point in its domain be continuous?
